# Force 1 Minute Gap Between Two Articles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to force a 1 minute gap between two articles posted by the same user. This is to prevent accidental double post and hopefully reduce spam.

Right now I am doing this in `User` model

```
public function canPostNewArticle()
{
    $article = Article::where('user_id', $this->id)->latest()->first();
    if ($article == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    $date = $article->created_at->timestamp;
    $currentTime = Carbon::now()->timestamp;

    $diff = ($currentTime - $date) / 60;
    return $diff > 1;
}
```

I am using this function to check before creating a new article. Is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the following query to decide whether the user has posted an article within a minute or not.

```
public function canPostNewArticle()
{
    return Article::where('user_id', $this->id)
        ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMinute())
        ->count() == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that is simpler and looks a bit better in my opinion is adding a where clause to the database call and instead of getting the first you get a count (amount that is created later then curten timestamp), if higher then 1 then you know the user have created an article within the last hour.

```
$oneHourAgo = strtotime() - 3600;
$oneHourAgoTimestamp = date('dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss', $oneHourAgo);

return Article::where('user_id', $this->id)->andWhere('created_at', '>', oneHourAgoTimestamp)->count() == 0;
```

I'm not 100% if my 2nd variable "oneHourAgoTimestamp" is having the correct format or not, but that can easily be modified.